# A single word for “home automation”

Tags: vocabulaire

I'm working in the IT field in Canada.

I was talking with someone from France and they had a single word for home automation.

It possibly sounded like *domitech*, but I'm not sure, as I only heard it once in conversation and my French isn't great.

Does anyone know what word I'm talking about?

*Possibly a combination of `domicile` and `automatisation`?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm French (from France) and lived for several years in Québec.

Yes, the word you want is "domotique". "domo" from latin domus, means home. Thus "domotique" is electronics that make your home building programmable.

The "--tique" suffix is more interesting. We call "Informatique" what the anglos call "computer science." If I wasn't French, I would most likely be pragmatic enough to concede that "computer science" is really the better term, because it explicitly says everything there is to say. But I'm a snobbish bastard froggie, so I will just huff instead.

But "informatiks" was invented by Germans... and we both got logistics and robotics.  Ten minutes of googling is enough to learn how to build a nuke, yet for the life of me it wasn't enough to figure out where the "-ics" suffix comes from... And, well, there's electro-nics.

So I went to dictionary.com and hit the -ic suffix:

> a suffix forming adjectives from other parts of speech, occurring originally in Greek and Latin loanwords ( metallic; poetic; archaic; public) and, on this model, used as an adjective-forming suffix with the particular senses “having some characteristics of” (opposed to the simple attributive use of the base noun) ( balletic; sophomoric); “in the style of” ( Byronic; Miltonic); “pertaining to a family of peoples or languages” ( Finnic; Semitic; Turkic).

In fact I'm so informed I still have no idea why it's called "domotique" but at least I tried.

Comment: Like _inform_**atique** is a [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) from _information_ and **automatique**, _dom_**otique** is compounded of _domicile_ and **automatique**, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Comme on le note dans les autres réponses, il s'agit de la [*domotique*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8388966), nom féminin, soit l' « ensemble de techniques adjoignant à celles du bâtiment les ressources de l'électronique, de l'informatique et des télécommunications pour améliorer l'habitat humain » ; on note aussi que « le terme *domotique* a été créé en France au milieu des années 80 pour répondre au besoin de nommer le concept jusque-là exprimé indirectement par *maison intelligente* » (GDT). On nous dit qu'il est formé du latin *domus* (maison) et d'*informatique* ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/domotique/26402?q=domotique#26280) en ligne) ; le concours du latin n'est pas nouveau. Il en résulte à mon avis un arrimage sans faille au sens impeccablement clair et parfaitement adapté à la langue française...

---

En effet, le terme [*informatique*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/informatique) a été créé à partir des mots *information* et [*automatique*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/automatique).<sup>1</sup> On peut utiliser [*ordinatique*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2071561) si on veut émuler le *computer* du *computer science* ; on se rappellera que le *traitement automatique de l'information* est un élément important de la discipline, pas moins que son support matériel. *Automatique* est formé avec [*automate*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/automate) suffixé en -*ique*.

Généralement, le suffixe [*-ique*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ique), « issu du latin -*icus* « relatif à, qui est propre à », [et] formateur de très nombreux adjectifs épicènes parfois employés substantivement et appartenant notamment au vocabulaire scientifique et technique. » est très productif au 19e dans des domaines comme la chimie, la géométrie, la médecine, et a « pris une grande extension au 20e siècle sous l'influence des nouvelles acquisitions scientifiques et techniques et de leur vulgarisation » (TLFi).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Indépendamment de l'origine étymologique du mot (l'allemand *informatik* de Karl Steinbuch), en français c'est bien le pionnier [Philippe Dreyfus](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_Dreyfus) qui le premier emploie le terme *informatique* dès 1962.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding the answer quicker than I expected looking at some random YouTube videos on the subject in French.

It's [domotique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domotique).